# How to use K-means clustering to visualise learnt features of a CNN model?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, representation-learning, k-means, contrastive-learning

Recently, I was going through the paper [Intriguing Properties of Contrastive Losses](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.02803). In the paper (section 3.2), the authors try to determine how well the SimCLR framework has allowed the ResNet50 Model to learn good quality/generalised features that exhibit hierarchical properties. To achieve this, they make use of K-means on intermediate features of the ResNet50 model (intermediate means o/p of block 2,3,4..), and I quote the reason below

> If the model learns good representations then regions of similar objects should be grouped together.

Final Results: [image: KMeans feature visualisation]

I am trying to replicate the same procedure but with a different model (like VggNet, Xception).

Are there any resources explaining how to perform such visualizations?